# Java Beginner Recursion with boolean

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, boolean

I don't understand why I am getting "return statement missing".

Here is the image with the code:
[image]

Comment: All paths do not return a value....

Comment: You´ve to return something in the elseif condition.

Comment: Please attach code as text, not as image. This would be much easier for others to read

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd and 3rd if conditions there are no returns.  Instead of your else, just return false.

So it reads:

```
    public class isTrans {
        public static boolean isTrans(String s,String t) {
            if (t.length()==1 && (s.charAt(s.length()-1))==t.charAt(0)){
                return true;
            } else if (s.charAt(0)==t.charAt(0)){
                return isTrans(s,t.substring(1));
            } else if (s.charAt(1)==t.charAt(1)){
                return isTrans(s,t.substring(1), t);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if i remove the else and only leave returns false i always get return false

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu sooooo muchhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to return in all the conditions or return at the end of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(/*...*/) {
    return true;
}
else if(/*...*/) {
    return isTrans(/*...*/); // return whatever isTrans returns
}
else if(/*...*/) {
    return isTrans(/*...*/); // here too
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the result of the function execution in your `else if`, so the recursion works properly. Like this:

```
return isTrans(s, t.substring(1))
```